# Altough I installed GSL library, g++ cannot compile my code

Tags: 14.04, compiling, gcc, c++

In order to use gnu gsl library I've installed it with the following command :

> sudo apt-get install libgsl0ldbl

When I write a simple c++ code just to check whether I installed it correctly or not, g++ says that

> fatal error: gsl/gsl_vector.h: No such file or directory

My code can be seen below :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gsl/gsl_vector.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_statistics.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
return 0;
}
```

what might be the reason ? Thanks in advance. [I'm trying to run it on ubuntu 14.04 64-Bit]

**edit**
I tried to compiled it with the following command

> g++ test.cpp

Comment: You need the `libgsl0-dev` package, I think

Comment: @steeldriver yeap, solved after I installed it. Could you explain the difference between them ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a number of libgsl packages, as shown by an `apt-cache search`:

```
$ apt-cache search libgsl
libgsl0-dbg - GNU Scientific Library (GSL) -- debug symbols package
libgsl0-dev - GNU Scientific Library (GSL) -- development package
libgsl0ldbl - GNU Scientific Library (GSL) -- library package
libocamlgsl-ocaml - GNU scientific library for OCaml
libocamlgsl-ocaml-dev - GNU scientific library for OCaml
```

In more detail, `apt-cache show libgsl0ldbl` includes the description

```
 This package provides the shared libraries required to run programs
 compiled with GNU GSL. To compile your own programs you also need to
 install libgsl0-dev.
```

whereas `apt-cache show libgsl0-dev` has

```
 This package contains the header files, static libraries and symbolic
 links that developers using GNU GSL will need.
```

so in this case you need to install `libgsl0-dev`

```
sudo apt-get install libgsl0-dev
```

This is quite a common distinction in the Ubuntu/Debian packaging system: there is usually a "runtime" package, and a "development" package that is indicated by a `-dev` suffix. The `-dev` package is the one to look for when building software from source - it will install the runtime package as a dependency if it is required.